# Why Android App - Re-started when the application stopped form the Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I am new to Android Development and I am developing an application to scan barcode using google vision API. In the application, I have three screens Splash Screen, Main Screen with two fragments (Scan & History) and Scanned Result. From the scan fragment, I am opening an activity called "ScannedResult" as soon as application scanned the barcode to show the result.

Now the problem is when I run the application from the Android Studio to the device.

**[Scenario# 0]** (From the Main activity screen app stopping that is the correct case)

1. Run the app
2. Splash Screen  -> Main Screen
3. Shows scan fragment and run successful flow
4. Now, STOP the application from the Android Studio.
5. Application stopped

**[Scenario# 1]** (But from ScannedResult activity app stops and start again why?)

1. Run the app
2. Splash Screen  -> Main Screen
3. Shows scan fragment and run successful flow
4. Now, Scan a Bar or QR Code then open ScannedResult (activity).
5. Now, STOP the application from the Android Studio.
6. Application stopped and show Black Screen
7. Application STARTED again and shows the Main Screen (Why it is starting again? I want to stop the application in this case).

Here I am suspecting something is wrong. Ideally, it must be stopped. Please help to identify where I am making mistake in the application.

[image]

Here is the **Manifest.xml** file

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.myapp.powertools.barcodescan">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="false"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".CreatePaypalUrl"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity"></activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateVcardForm"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateLocationForm"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateWifiForm"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateEventForm"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateSmsForm"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateEmailForm"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateTelephoneForm"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateWebsiteForm"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity android:name=".Main2Activity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".GenerateQrCode"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".CreateTextForm"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name=".ScannedResult"
            android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity" />


        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />


        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="barcode" />
    </application>

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

</manifest>
```

**Scan.java** file

```
 barcodeDetector.setProcessor(new Detector.Processor<Barcode>() {
                @Override
                public void release() {

                }

                @Override
                public void receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections) {
                    final SparseArray<Barcode> qrCodes = detections.getDetectedItems();

                    if (qrCodes.size() > 0) {
                        if (isScanned == false) {
                            barcodeDetector.release();
                            isScanned = true;

                            String dataType = getBarcodeType(qrCodes.valueAt(0));
                            String dataValue = qrCodes.valueAt(0).displayValue;
                            String rawValue = qrCodes.valueAt(0).rawValue;

                            Intent intentScannedResult = new Intent(getActivity(), ScannedResult.class);
                            intentScannedResult.putExtra("barcode_raw_value", rawValue);
                            intentScannedResult.putExtra("barcode_value", dataValue);
                            intentScannedResult.putExtra("barcode_type", dataType);
                            intentScannedResult.putExtra("is_scanner", "1");
                            startActivity(intentScannedResult);
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Sometimes android studio plays badly, try to clean project and build it again. Also, try once File>Indicate caches/restart.

Comment: I have tried, but no luck. Is that I am doing something wrong in an open new activity?

Comment: The code for start new activity seems good to me.

Comment: You can debug `onResume()` method and you can see when it can again. Maybe that can help you.

Comment: I have already checked onRsume() but no solution.

Comment: Maybe then it's hard to find what is an actual issue without looking/debugging your code for me.